# Issue with serialPort_DataReceived event

Tags: c#, events, serial-port

I have  a function under class Communication

```
    public int SerialCommunciation()
    {
        /*Function for opening a serial port with default settings*/
        InitialiseSerialPort();

        /*This section of code will try to write to the COM port*/   
        WriteDataToCOM();

        /*An event handler */                   
       _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);

       return readData;
    }
```

Here

```
     int readData /*is a global variable*/
```

The _serialPortDataRecieved() updates the variable readData according to the data read from serial port

```
   /* Method that will be called when there is data waiting in the buffer*/
    private void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

       string text = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
       int.TryParse(text, out readData);

    }
```

Now when i called this function from another class

```
   valueReadFromCom=Communication.SerialCommunication()
```

I needed to get the value read from serial port but instead i got 0.
When i tried debugging this code, i found out that control first goes to statement

```
   return readData;
```

in function SerialCommunication and only then control goes to function  _serialPort_DataRecieved, function triggered by event. How can i make the whole process synchronous, that means readData should be returned from the function serialCommunication only after the function _serial_DataRecieved is performed.

Comment: Just don't use DataReceived here, you have no use for it.  Read directly from the port by using one of the Read() methods.  You'll need to fix your code, ReadExisting() can't work and TryParse returns a bool.

Comment: i just used TryParse for converting a string to integer to store it in variable ReadData...If there is no dataReceived Event then what will happen if there is no data to read from serial port??...when i added thread sleep, actually this code is returning the integer value..I also feel that there is so problem with way im doing this ...If you can suggest a way then it will be very helpful...

Comment: Using Sleep() is a hack to make ReadExisting work.  A very imperfect one.  You need to focus on writing code that ensures that you got the complete response from the device.  Like storing the received bytes in a buffer until you get the last one, then parse it.  There isn't any info in your question that will help us help you to make that happen, you didn't describe what the device sends.

Comment: Okay. I have a PIC programmed to create different temperature cycles. Now im creating a user interface for that. From UI, the user should be able to specify as well read  different temperatures . So i have a set of commands designed for this. Suppose if there is command 1, to read temperature of cycle one. On passing command 1 by WriteDataToCOM(), i should get temperature of cycle one. Here communication between PC and device is through COM port. This is minimal thing i need to establish. Please suggest correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be adviced that the following is not the right way as serial port works async. On the otherhand it does the job anyway.

Just add a boolen property and check this property before returning from SerialCommunication function; set this property to true when data is received.

```
private bool dataReceived = false;   

public int SerialCommunciation()
{
    /*Function for opening a serial port with default settings*/
    InitialiseSerialPort();

    /*This section of code will try to write to the COM port*/
    WriteDataToCOM();

    /*An event handler */
    _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);

    while (!dataReceived)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    return readData;
}

private void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   string text = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
   int.TryParse(text, out readData);
   _serialPort_DataReceived = true;
}
```

Comment: _serialPort_DataReceived = true;

this statement is confusing me

Comment: Is it possible to add two or more event like `_serialPort_DataReceived`?